# Push to array with AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to build a favourite system with AsyncStorage in React Native. On my ProductDetailScreen I have the corresponding `ProdID` available. I'd like to save the `ProdID` to AsyncStorage.

```
  const arr = [];
  const saveFavorites = async () => {
    arr.push(ProdID);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("FAVORITES", JSON.stringify(arr));
  };

  const getFavorites = async () => {
    const favs = await AsyncStorage.getItem("FAVORITES");
    let parsedFavs = JSON.parse(favs);
    console.log(parsedFavs);
  };
```

This works. However if I go to the next Product and click the saveFavorites button, obviously the `arr` gets initiated with an empty array.

I can't wrap my head around how I would create the empty array if the saveFavorites button was never clicked before but push to the array if there is already an ID in it. I tried it with useState and useEffect but without success. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like

```
const saveFavorites = async () => {
 let data = await AsyncStorage.getItem("FAVORITES");

let arr = JSON.parse(data);
    arr.push(ProdID);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("FAVORITES", JSON.stringify(arr));
  };
```

try with this

Comment: Ok, still a little problem. If there array is completely empty at the beginning, I get this error `[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'arr.push')]`

Comment: you can do something like 

```arr ? arr.push(ProdID): [];```

Comment: hope it helps , feel free for doubts

Comment: Thanks. It only works if I do it like this: `arr ? arr.push(ProdId) : (arr = [ProdId]);`

Only problem left ist, to check if ProdId is already in arr so that it does not get pushed into the array.